# OPENGL glReadPixels how to get larger window content?

Tags: opengl

I want to get the window content from OpenGL to OpenCV. The code used below:

```
    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[ Win_width * Win_height * 4];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, Win_width, Win_height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    cv::Mat image_flip(Win_height, Win_width, CV_8UC4, buffer);
```

When the window size is small. everything is fine.
But when Win_width and Win_height large than 1080p, the image will be resize to 1080p and other part will pad with grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render to and read from a FBO so you don't run afoul of the [pixel ownership test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing/Pixel_ownership_test):

> Because the Default Framebuffer is owned by a resource external to
>   OpenGL, it is possible that particular pixels of the default
>   framebuffer are not owned by OpenGL. And therefore, OpenGL cannot
>   write to those pixels. Fragments aimed at such pixels are therefore
>   discarded at this stage of the pipeline.
>
> Generally speaking, if the window you are rendering to is partially
>   obscured by another window, the pixels covered by the other window are
>   no longer owned by OpenGL and thus fail the ownership test. Any
>   fragments that cover those pixels will be discarded. This also
>   includes framebuffer clearing operations.
>
> **Note that this test *only* affects rendering to the default framebuffer.
>   When rendering to a Framebuffer Object, all fragments pass this test.**

Comment: That can also be much faster, since reading back pixel data back from GPU is a very slow operation.

Comment: @BЈовић: FBOs are also on the GPU.

Comment: @NicolBolas But they have options to optimize read direction, which may be ignored by the driver. No?

Comment: @BЈовић: OpenGL read-back operations don't have any special options based on whether the source of the read command is an FBO or the default framebuffer. PBOs for example work either way.

Comment: @NicolBolas My mistake. I meant [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) - GL_STATIC_READ_ARB, GL_DYNAMIC_READ_ARB and GL_STREAM_READ_ARB should be optimized for read.

Comment: @BЈовић Yes, I should use FBO instead of the current one. The current one restricted to the Screen resolution.